# react-native run-android punycode npm error

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

When I want to start my project with the react-native run-android command, node and npm give the following error:

> (node:14664) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I also get same error...
No idea how to resolve it

Comment: I update my react-native version. that can fixed.